# What is parallel library in C# .net for Longs.toByteArray from Java to .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, byte, endianness

What is parallel library in C# .net for  Longs.toByteArray from Java(com.google.common.primitives.Longs) to .NET C#.

In Java its
public static byte[] toByteArray(long value)
Returns a big-endian representation of value in an 8-element byte array; equivalent to ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(value).array(). For example, the input value 0x1213141516171819L would yield the byte array {0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19}.

But how to do same thing in .NET C#

Comment: `BinaryWriter` or `BinaryPrimitives`

Comment: [BitConverter.GetBytes(long)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=net-6.0#system-bitconverter-getbytes(system-int64))

Answer (score 0):

You probably look for:

```cs
long myLongValue = 12345;
var longBytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(myLongValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. It can achieved using following method

public static byte[] toByteArray(long value)
{

```
           byte[] result = new byte[8];
           for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                 result[i] = (byte)(value & 0xffL);
                 value >>= 8;
            }
           return result;
    }
```